# Remove Mercurial versioning from a folder

Tags: mercurial

I currently have a project versioned using Mercurial. On my computer, there is a `.hg` folder in the root of my local repository.

I want to change from Mercurial to Git, so I'm wondering if removing the `.hg` folder is enough to remove Mercurial versioning from this folder?

If not, what can I do? (I don't want to move the existing sources on my computer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes that should work.

mercurial stores chancesets and so on in the .hg folder, but you will lose all your projects history if you just delete the .hg folder and use git instead then.

Comment: There are a few files outside of the `.hg` folder that you'll want to convert or delete too. They usually start with `.hg` too. For example, `.hgignore` and `.hgsub`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all the bits that make it a Mercurial repository are in the .hg folder so you can delete that to remove the Mercurial versioning.

Note though that doing this will obviously lose all your source control history as well.

Looks like there are some options to convert the repository if you want to keep that history, first hit on google:

http://arr.gr/blog/2011/10/bitbucket-converting-hg-repositories-to-git/